# Реляционный запрос Yii

Tags: php, yii

Всем привет, помогите пожалуйста, у меня есть 2 таблицы

```
tb_users
{
id
username
password
email
}

tb_coupon
{
id
user_id
}
```

Мне нужно имея user_id из tb_coupon получить логин пользователя, я в модели Coupon написал реляционный запрос

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'user'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Users', 'username'),
    );
}
```

Но когда я обращаюсь к этому

```
$profile = Coupon::model()->findByPk(36);
echo $profile->user;
```

Получаю ошибку

```
Не определено свойство "Coupon.username".
```

Делал на офф. документации, помогите пожалуйста, что я сделал не так?

```
 <?php
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Coupon');

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'summaryText'=>false,
    'columns'=>array(
        'place'=>array(
            'name'=>'place',
            'value'=>'$row + 1',
            'header'=>'Место',
        ),
        'username'=>array(
            'name'=>'username',
            'value'=>'Coupon::model()->user',
            'header'=>'Логин',
        ),
    ),
));
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

вообще то на сколько помню чтоб вытащить подтаблицы запросом нада так записать

```
$profile = Coupon::model()->with('user')->findByPk(36);
```

with('user') - указывает с какими связями загружаем данные

данные выводятся вот так

```
$profile->getRelated("user")->username
```

Comment: Выполнил код, ошибки нету, но ничего не выводится, при попытке сделать

    echo $profile->username;

Появляется ошибка, что Coupon.username не найден, подскажите, как вывести информацию

Comment: Нужно:

    echo $profile->user->username;

Comment: Спасибо большое, не знал, теперь знаю :)

Answer (score 1):

Нужно так:

```
'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Users', 'user_id'),
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я сделал небольшую ошибку в вопросе, я реляционный запрос писал не в Users модели, а в Coupon, и теперь он ошибки не выдаёт, но и данные не выводит.

*P.S* Обновил первый пост, указал код виджета.

Comment: Почитайте http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/database.arr